# 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all' not working, How to get all countries now?

Tags: asp.net-core, country-codes, mobile-country-code

Before week ago, https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all was giving country code but now it is not working so how can someone use it to get all country code.

Code throws **The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure** from where the rest call made of 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all' this API.

Any alternate API to get all country code, name and flag. as we are using it at ASP.Net side, front-end side(Angular) Andriod, and iOS App. It would be better to have API.

Comment: what do you mean by "become secure"?

Comment: I am working on support project and API was working fine before but suddenly it start throwing 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure' error from rest call made of 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all'

Comment: Seems the cert is invalid. The only one who can fix this is the provider of this api, or you decide to ignore invalid certs (which isn't a good idea and may not even be possible under certain conditions, for instance in an iOS App)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The same issue on their git repo](https://github.com/apilayer/restcountries/issues/253).

This is now available in [v2 version](https://restcountries.com/v2/all) and [v3 version](https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all) on `restcountries.com`.
Response takes some time and it has a lot of information.